# requests.auth update parameters

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

How to update (add) a parameter (signature) to request.body ?

'''import hashlib
import hmac
import time

```
import requests
from requests.auth import AuthBase

from config import key, secret


class BinanceAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret = api_secret
        self.url_v2 = 'https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v2/{}'

    def __call__(self, request):
        signature = hmac.new(bytes(self.api_secret, 'latin-1'),
                             bytes((request.body or ""), 'latin-1'),
                             digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
        
        request.headers.update(
            {'X-MBX-APIKEY': self.api_key}
        )
        return request'''
```

Comment: What is your parameter?

Comment: parameter - signature

Comment: Have you tries this: `x = requests.post(url, data =signature)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, `request` is a prepared request object, where you have already included the POST data and want to include the signature based on this data. You could do something like `request.body += ('&' if request.body else '') + f'signature={signature}'` in order to add the signature, since the signature is a hexdigest and doesn't include any bad charcters (url invalid characters).

EDIT:

```py
if request.body is not None:
   request.body = ('&' if request.body else '') + f'signature={signature}'
else:
   request.prepare_body({'signature':signature},None)
```

Comment: I have tried:  unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: Edited my answer to include the case where body is None